# How to remove punctuation from a string/list

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
UserSentence = input('Enter your chosen sentence: ')
UserSentence = UserSentence.split()
print(UserSentence)
```

say the `UserSentence` was `'life is short, stunt it'`, how would I remove the comma after `.split()`? if possible.

Answer (score 3):

replace before you split:

```
In [4]:  'life is short, stunt it'.replace(',',' ').split()
Out[4]: ['life', 'is', 'short', 'stunt', 'it']
```

If you want to remove all punctuation, you can use `str.translate` to replace any punctuation with a space and then split:

```
s = 'life is short, stunt it!!?'

from string import punctuation

tbl = str.maketrans({ord(ch):" " for ch in punctuation})


print(s.translate(tbl).split())
```

Output:

```
['life', 'is', 'short', 'stunt', 'it']
```

Comment: thanks very much. i have a few questions: 1. what does the from string import punctuation do? 2. what does tbl = str.maketrans({ord(ch):" " for ch in punctuation}) do?